# Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server in Next JS

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js14

I've been getting error "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server" in next js project.
I've the following code parts..

Navbar.jsx

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'

import { getLanguageData } from '@/utils/api_fetching/commonApi'
import { langCode } from '@/utils/common/helperMethods'
import LanguageSelect from './LanguageSelect'
import NavItem from './NavItem'
import NavAuth from './NavAuth'

const Navbar = async ({ setting_data }) => {
    let lang_resp_data = await getLanguageData()
    let lang_code = langCode()

    return (
        <>
            <header className="header-wraper">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                    <div className="container-xxl">
                        <Link className="navbar-brand p-0 me-0" href="/">
                            <img src={setting_data && setting_data.general && setting_data.general.website_logo ? setting_data.general.website_logo : "/assets/images/logo.png"} 
                                className="img-fluid responsive-img" alt="website_logo" width="192"
                            />
                        </Link>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler d-none" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <NavItem />
                        <div className="d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap m-auto">
                            <NavAuth />
                            
                            <div className="select-dropdown">
                                <LanguageSelect lang_data={lang_resp_data} lang_code={lang_code} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

NavItem.jsx

```
"use client"

import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";


const NavItem = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const isActive = (href) => pathname === href;

    function on_click(path){
        router.push(path)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="collaps navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-0 align-items-center flex-row">
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <Link onClick={() => on_click("/")} href="#" className={`nav-link dropdown-toggle ${isActive("/") && "active"}`} data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Influencers
                        </Link>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu p-0 m-0 border-0 dropdown-menuleftside">
                            <div className="submenu-navitem">
                                <div className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap">
                                    <div className="d-flex flex-column left-submenu">
                                        <h6 className="submenu-title">HOW IT WORKS</h6>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Find collaborations</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Create Smart Links</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Collaborate with Brands</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="d-flex flex-column right-submenu">
                                        <h6 className="submenu-title">OUR SERVICES</h6>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Smart Link Creation</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Bulk Link Creation</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Connect Social Media (Coming Soon)</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Campaign (Coming Soon)</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li className="ligap-32">
                        <img src="/assets/images/navradio.png" alt="" className="img-fluid" />
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <Link onClick={() => on_click("/brands-home")} className={`nav-link dropdown-toggle ${isActive("/brands-home") && "active"}`} href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Brands
                        </Link>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menurightside p-0 m-0 border-0">
                            <div className="submenu-navitem">
                                <div className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap">
                                    <div className="d-flex flex-column left-submenu">
                                        <h6 className="submenu-title">HOW IT WORKS</h6>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Find collaborations</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Create Smart Links</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Collaborate with Brands</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="d-flex flex-column right-submenu">
                                        <h6 className="submenu-title">OUR SERVICES</h6>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Smart Link Creation</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Bulk Link Creation</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">User Management</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Manage Stats</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Create Campaign (Coming Soon)</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" className="sunmenu-link">Manage Campaign (Coming Soon)</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default NavItem
```

NavAuth.jsx

```
"use client"

import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import Link from 'next/link'

import { userProfile } from '@/redux_store/customer/customerAction'


const NavAuth = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let user_profile = useSelector((state) => state.userProfile)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(userProfile())
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            { user_profile.logged_in ?
                <div className="my-account d-flex align-items-center position-relative">
                    <div className="img-myaccount d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center me-3">
                        <img src="/assets/images/myaccount-img.png" alt="img.." className="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                    <h6 className="text-white text-20">My Account</h6>
                </div>
                :
                <>
                    <Link href="/signup" className="btn btn-sucess text-white me-3 me-sm-4">Sign Up It’s Free</Link>
                    <Link href="/login" className="btn btn-login text-white">Login</Link>
                </>
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default NavAuth
```

When I comment the NavAuth component in Navbar.jsx the error is gone, there are certain other logs in my console like

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <main>.

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Error: There was an error while hydrating this Suspense boundary. Switched to client rendering.
```

Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in Navbar.jsx

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const NavAuth = dynamic(() => import('./NavAuth'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work but thanks anyway

Comment: What error are you facing in this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurred due to redux saga, in there I've some related state. It was because of that error is occurred.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).